# jQuery animate({left:"+=10"}) not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#start").animate({ left: "+=10px" }, 1000)
            .animate({ left: "-5000px" }, 1000);
    });
</script>

<p id="start">this is some text that i am going to animate </p>
```

I am racking my brain here as to why this doesn't animate. If I change `left` to `marginLeft` it will work as expected and animates. But i am not sure why `left` doesn't.

Can anyone explain please? I have seen many other scripts doing something similar.

Comment: What's your CSS look like for `#start`? It needs to be positioned absolutely (`position: absolute`) or fixed (`position: fixed`).

Comment: I guess it depends on where the <p> is in the markup and which style it has. Is it positioned? relative? absolute? floated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For positioning to work, you need to have enabled it by setting the `position` css property.

Set it to `fixed` or `absolute` or `relative` to work (*depending on what you try to achieve*)

Quoting from the specs of the [`position` <sup>MDC docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) property.

> **Initial value** : *static*

and

> **static**
>       Normal behavior.  The *top*, *right*, *bottom*, and *left* properties do not
>   apply.

Comment: @Marko, yes i was updating to a more complete answer.. thanks.

Comment: wooo hooo thanks a million folks , really appreciate it .. I can glue my hair back now :)

Answer (score 1):

You set the position of this `<p>` to `absolute`

like: `p{position:absolute;}` otherwise use `marginLeft` instead of `left`